Orthogonal complement of null vector
I am trying to solve excercise 8.5 d) from Straumanns book on general relativity (here V is an n-dimensional Minkowski vector space):
Prove that the orthogonal complement of a null vector is an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$ in which the inner product is positive semi-definite and has rank $n-2$.
I understand that every null vector is orthogonal to itself or any linearly dependent vector. But can't a spacelike vector also be orthogonal to a null vector? Also how can one show that the inner product of the orthogonal complement to the null vector has rank (n-2)?

With a suitable choice of the reference frame the null vecotr is always either of the form $(a,0,...,0,a)$ or $(-a,0,...,0,a)$ ($a \neq 0$).  Hence the considered space is generated by n-2 spacelike vectors and respectively $(-1,0,...,0,1)$ or $(1,0,...,0,1)$...

Ah thank you, this cleared things up!
